# Making a request to server through sTunnel

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, stunnel

I've got a small app running on en EC2 instance that' configured through sTunnel.

My sTunnel is configured like so

```
client = no
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
key = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
[proxy]
connect = 127.0.0.1:3000
accept = private_ip:1500
```

My understanding here is that I can send a request to `private_ip:1500` and that will hand off to the process running on local host but when I try to send something to the ip address I get a `ETIMEDOUT` error.

Here's how I'm making the request:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var net = require('net');

var HOST = 'private_ip';
var PORT = 1500;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {

console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    // Close the client socket completely
client.destroy();

});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

Server is listening as follows:

```
var config = require('./config/config.js');
var net = require('net');
var timer = require('./timer.js');

const server = require('net').createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true });
const child = require('child_process').fork('anotherProcess.js', ['child']);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    child.send('socket', socket);
});

server.listen(config.proxy.port, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port ' + 
config.proxy.port);
});

server.on('error', function(err) {
    if (err.code === 'EADDRINUSE') {
        console.log('Address in use, retrying...');
        setTimeout(function() {
            server.close();
            server.listen(config.proxy.port);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is your server listening? Is it binding on `127.0.0.1`? Also, did you update your security group to allow port 1500?

Comment: Updated question to include server. Security group accepts tcp on port 1500 yep.

Comment: Since this is a network issue, you should add a bit more information about the network. Where is the client running? Where is the server running? How are they connected? etc.

Comment: Hmm that's what I was afraid of as I'm not a networks guy. For the purposes of this test I've got two VMs. One client and one server. Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say how are they connected?

Comment: Are they both EC2 instances? Are they in the same VPC? Same security group? Can you ping between the two machines? Do you see the packets coming in on the server at all?

Comment: The server is on an EC2 instance - the client is on another VM that I don't have access to however they have the private IP and port where to send the packets. I can successfully send packets from a vagrant VM running locally to the public IP on port 3000 however when I try to send packets to the private IP on port 1500 I get the error `[Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'`.

Comment: Are you saying the VM is not in EC2? How do you expect it to reach the private IP? Is there a VPN?

Comment: Hm, yes the client isn't in EC2. As to weather or not there's a VPN I think there must be. From the live environment I can see the following: `LOG5[933]: Service [proxy] accepted connection from ***.***.*.**:****` but then I can see immediately `OG3[933]: SSL_accept: Peer suddenly disconnected`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158182/discussion-between-rob-gleeson-and-kichik).